# incrementing an integer using persistence data in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on creating a shop for my game. In the game a user will collect coins and have the ability to use the coins for purchases in the shop.

I therefor followed Unity's guide to Saving and loading persistence data. Since the user should not loose their coins when they quit the game.

I have the problem that when the user reopens the game and collect new coins it will override the saved amount from their gameplay.

This is my save function to save the collected coins from a gameplay:

```
public void Save() {
        coins = Coins.value;

        Debug.Log("Saving");

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/coins.dat");
        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();

            data.coins = coins;

            bf.Serialize(file, data);
            file.Close();
}
```

The persistence is working, by that I mean if the user collects 10 coins and then restart the game he will be able to see the amount of 10 coins. But as soon as he plays again and collects 5 coins, he will then see 5 and not 15.

I tried to increment such as:

```
 data.coins += coins;
```

But that did not work..

Is the way to somehow load the amount before using my save method. So somehow get the data.coins value from the load method and then add with the value to the Coins.value from the save method?

My load method looks like this:

```
if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/coins.dat"))

 {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/coins.dat", FileMode.Open);
        PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

        coins = data.coins;
      }
     }   
    }


[Serializable]
class PlayerData {

public int coins;

}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in this code. If you load and have the correct amount of coins, then that part of your code is working.

Comment: @4ndy the problem is the next time the player plays the game and collect new coins, the new coin amount will override the amount from the run before.

Comment: the problem isnt in the code you 've shown us, Im guessing this loads and some  how coins is reset.. you need to put in some debugs and trace the code we dont have

Comment: Can you post the code where it triggers the player collecting the new coins? Where is the variable `coins` at, and how it is accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling us you increment by using

```
data.coins += coins;
```

but having a look at your save method

```
public void Save()
{
    // HERE YOU OVERWRITE coins
    coins = Coins.value;

    Debug.Log("Saving");

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/coins.dat");
    PlayerData data = new PlayerData();

    // YOU CREATE A NEW DATA OBJECT AND ASSIGN coins WHICH BASICALLY NOW EQUALS Coins.Value
    data.coins = coins;

    bf.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();
}
```

compared to the load method

```
if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/coins.dat"))

{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/coins.dat", FileMode.Open);
    PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
    file.Close();

    // YOU LOAD INTO coins, NOT INTO Coins.Value
    coins = data.coins;
}
```

There seem to be three different places where the amount is stored: `data.coins`, `Coins.value` and `coins` .. you should stick to only one and probably rather directly increment

```
Coins.Value += coins;
```

save

```
data.coins = Coins.Value;
```

and load into

```
Coins.Value = data.coins;
```